# "A cannot be cast to B" error while trying to use clone()

Tags: java, casting, clone

I won't be posting the whole code as I would like to try and fix this myself but maybe someone here could point me in the right direction.
Code I am using (Edited to show more):

```
class GeometricObject implements Cloneable{
    private String color = "white";
    private boolean filled;
    private java.util.Date dateCreated;
    private double side;
(some other stuff before this)
}
public abstract class Octagon extends GeometricObject implements Comparable, Cloneable {
    public static void test() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        GeometricObject obj1 = new GeometricObject("white", true, 5) ;
        Octagon obj1Clone = (Octagon)((Octagon)obj1).clone();
        }

    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
            Octagon obj1Clone = (Octagon) super.clone();
            return obj1Clone;
    }
```

The error code I am getting once I run the code is
task3.Octagon$1 cannot be cast to task3.Octagon
To try and make everything work I made the
Object obj is created by doing
`GeometricObject obj1 = new GeometricObject("white", true, 5) {};`
Since it was object of GeometricObject, while trying to fix this I have had put the implememts Cloneable(), ive have tried putting GeometricObject into diff parts of the  `Octagon obj1Clone = (Octagon)((Octagon)obj1).clone();` to just try and luck out if I had done it incorrectly. I completely understand if you are unable to help me because of the lack of code I am giving you.
And before you say it, I know clone() isn't used much nowadays but this is a task so I do have to use it.
Thank you!

Comment: The default `clone()` behavior doesn't create an object of a different type. Note that the actual type of your object appears to be of an anonymous inner class of `Octagon`, not a `GeometricObject`. It's hard to tell what's going on or what you're trying to achieve - a [mcve] would make all of this much clearer.

Comment: @JonSkeet I added some more code, I hope this enough to give you a idea. Thank you.

Comment: Fundamentally, you *cannot* cast an object to a type that it isn't an instance of. Your `obj1` is a `GeometricObject`, but it's not an `Octagon` - so the cast fails before you even get as far as the cloning. While you may need to use cloning eventually, that's not your first problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet Alright thank you, I will look into this. Thank you!